# Return from on function to another javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two functions and am trying to return something from the second function. Not sure what I am doing wrong. I keep getting `undefined` in the alert.

```
function a(){
    var testMe = b("hello");
    alert(testMe);  
}

function b(theVar){
    var returnVar = theVar;
    return returnVar;   
}
```

Comment: Works fine for me. When I call `a()`, unless you are not talking about the alert that is in `a`.

Comment: It works for me. Please post a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net).

Comment: Show how you are calling the function

Comment: Its perfect and working. I don't see anything wrong in it.

Comment: unless there is some more code which you haven't provided for us...

Comment: Can't reproduce the problem.

Comment: Try `b.call("hello");`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as you can see here, is working: http://jsfiddle.net/hCGu8/

**CODE**

```
function a(){
    var testMe = b("hello");
    alert(testMe);  
}

function b(theVar){
    var returnVar = theVar + " returned";
    return returnVar;   
}

a();
```

Comment: to whoever is downvoting, at least explain why.

Comment: I think it's because this is just a copy of OP question saying everything is working. I think OP's problem is somewhere else.

Comment: by the data provided by SeeleyBoothe, the solution is that everything works..

Comment: @Benders I Like the simplicity of in your comment.

Comment: I don't understand if it was sarcastic or not, anyway simplicity is the key to everything!

Comment: This was already been posted as comment by some other user. Having duplicate suggestion just make our finger pain by scrolling on the mouse over and over again with no sense.

Comment: @Mr_Green by the time he posted (18 secs before me) I was typing my answer..

Comment: I said "_posted as comment_" not answer. Anyway I am cool. (I am not the downvoter)

Comment: my bad then, next time I'll watch comments carefully .

Comment: Not sure. I must have something else mucked up!

Comment: I didn't downvote, but I think providing an answer even if there is nothing wrong (i.e. no problem exists) it pointless. The question should be closed instead since it is unlikely that it will help anyone in the future.

Answer (score 0):

This sound right to me... and in fact I happen to have "hello" in the alert:

```
function a(){
    var testMe = b("hello");
    alert(testMe);  
}

function b(theVar){
    var returnVar = theVar;
    return returnVar;   
}

a();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/u7zPY/

Comment: Yeah. I did the same. Same result.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the code.

Answer (score 0):

Your question subject says "Return from on function" and your tags mention `jQuery`, while the code in the question works fine.

I'm working on the assumption that you have reduced your test case too far and removed the problem from it (in future, please **test** your reduced test cases to ensure they still demonstrate the problem!) and that you actually have something like this:

```
function a() {
    var result = jQuery('foo').on('click', function () { return 1; });
    //                         ^^ This being the on function
}
```

… and you want `result` to equal `1`.

This is impossible.

`on` just assigns an event handler to run later. The execution of `a` will finish before that event fires. You can't return anything from an event handler to the function that assigns it.

You can use a callback, in which you define a function to run when the data is available. This works in exactly the same was as the function you pass as the second argument to `on`:

```
function a(callback) {
    var result = jQuery('foo').on('click', function () { callback(1); });
}

a(function (result) { alert(result); });
```